# How to deploy .war in node of own choice in Wildfly cluster?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-16, wildfly-cluster

I have deployed a .war and WF choose itself one of 3 node and deploys in same. (01,02,03)

I want to .war to shift from say 03 to 02 manually. (not redeploy again and again and see when it will choose).

As of now following file is there in jboss deployment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<singleton-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:singleton-deployment:1.0"/>
```

How is it possible in Wildfly? (Wildfly 16)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care which node? If you only want to deploy to a single node, only place in the deployments directory of that node